How to remove consecutive rows with duplicate values in ClickHouse time series?
Is there a way to store time series data in ClickHouse and remove successive rows with the same value? For example, given the following data:
Currently, I have more than 10 billion rows, with more than 90% the same value with different timestamps.
key, timestamp, value
1, 0, 12
1, 1, 12
1, 2, 12
1, 3, 13
1, 4, 14
1, 5, 14
1, 6, 12

I want to query or preprocess it so that the result is:
key, timestamp, value
1, 0, 12
1, 3, 13
1, 4, 14
1, 6, 12

If not, what would be the best way to achieve this in ClickHouse?

Use rowNumber or denseRank to create a sequential row number for ordering your time series.
Use lag or lead functions to compare the current row with the previous row.
Filter rows where the current value is different from the previous one (i.e., removing consecutive duplicates).
